# Split list by 2 delimiters

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataset, kaggle

I have a dataset to extract values from "Value" column but it was two delimiters **e.g. 130 [23 - 40.2]**

I tried to split with one delimiter first but was unable to combine the splits as it's now a list.

```
x = prob["Value"]
left = x.str.split("[")[0]
print(left)
```

Appreciate the help. Cheers

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. What is the "value column"? The example data you showed has more than two delimiters (depending on how you define the term). Splitting a string by definition returns a list so I don't understand why that surprises you. You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you mean that a value such as `130 [23 - 40.2]` should be converted into two values, `130` and `23 - 40.2`, you should say so. Which is to say, you should clarify how you want to interpret that string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `str.extract`and `regex`:

```
left = x.str.extract(r"\[(.*?) -")
right = x.str.extract(r"- (.*?)\]")
```